# How to synchronise Bootstrap 4 carousels with one set of controls?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

By using bootstrap 4 carousel utilities (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/), how can I synchronize a carousel with controls to a carousel without any controls?

1) When the control arrows are clicked upon, both carousels will slide at the same time.

2) When either of the carousel is hovered upon, they will both stop sliding automatically.

3) When the 2 carousels are not hovered upon, they will slide together at the same time automatically. (After each set time interval).

This is the layout of the two carousels. They are both placed within a equal width column inside a row. The right carousel (without controls) contains descriptive texts corresponding to the image displayed on the left carousel.

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVdbe.jpg)

I have tried a few stackoverflow solutions but have no luck.

```
<div class="col-6 p-5 text-center">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide py-5 mb-4 carousel-sync" data-ride="carousel" >
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active mt-3 mx-2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class="mx-2 mt-3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class=" mx-2 mt-3"></li>
   </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/img2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/img3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-control" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-control" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

</div>



<div class="col-6 align-middle">
<div id="carouselExamplSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide carousel-sync" data-ride="carousel" >

 <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active carouseltext">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ultricies, velit ut sollicitudin ultricies, diam ipsum interdum nisi, non imperdiet libero tellus id enim. Etiam venenatis vulputate massa, luctus fringilla tellus accumsan a. Donec varius gravida efficitur. In eu nibh dui. Vivamus maximus libero dui, id congue nisl viverra sed. Nam vitae bibendum lectus. Pellentesque sed ligula at metus facilisis cursus.


    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item carouseltext ">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ultricies, velit ut sollicitudin ultricies, diam ipsum interdum nisi, non imperdiet libero tellus id enim. Etiam venenatis vulputate massa, luctus fringilla tellus accumsan a. Donec varius gravida efficitur. In eu nibh dui. Vivamus maximus libero dui, id congue nisl viverra sed. Nam vitae bibendum lectus. Pellentesque sed ligula at metus facilisis cursus.


    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item carouseltext ">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ultricies, velit ut sollicitudin ultricies, diam ipsum interdum nisi, non imperdiet libero tellus id enim. Etiam venenatis vulputate massa, luctus fringilla tellus accumsan a. Donec varius gravida efficitur. In eu nibh dui. Vivamus maximus libero dui, id congue nisl viverra sed. Nam vitae bibendum lectus. Pellentesque sed ligula at metus facilisis cursus.


    </div>
  </div>


</div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very straight forward solution and considering both the carousels have equal number of slides.. what you can do is:

1. Create one carousel
2. Each of the carousel item will be the full layout as shown in your image
3. You can reposition the arrows with overriding the default CSS.

Hope this helps